Python Selenium specified download directory no longer working
I have python code that downloads a report using selenium and chromedriver, I have also specified an exact download path that was working previously. There has been no update to chrome as I've disabled updates to keep chromedriver working. This is the section of code relevant to the download path and driver being initialized, it is usually run as a packaged .exe successfully, but now when running prompts for download location. Can someone give me some insight as to why the download path was working previously but has stopped working?
# Define download path
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory': r"E:\My Drive\check\\"}
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", prefs)

# Initialize Chrome WebDriver
service = Service(driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)


It's probably because of selenium package update, try
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

